# Do transactions store information on when they were created?

Tags: stellar-core, xdr

I'm looking at the [XDR definition](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/xdr/Stellar-transaction.x) for `transaction` and I can't find if there's any info on when a transaction was created.

How do I look up date information for a transaction? I want to get some perspective on time from the Postgres database

Comment: No idea how to get that from a stellar-core, but you can get the created_at date from a stellar-horizon server (I assume that is the date when the transaction was written into a ledger, a transaction itself does not contain a date). API: `https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/txId` SQL: `SELECT created_at FROM history_transactions WHERE transaction_hash="txID"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction can optionally contain timebounds, placing a lower and upper bound on when it may be executed.  However, if you want to know whether and exactly when the transaction was executed, you need to query the blockchain history, e.g., by querying horizon for the txID.  Here's the appropriate documentation for the transaction endpoint:

https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/transactions-single.html